# Best way to write a string without "rewriting it" each loop iteration

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm trying to write a new string with a for loop but each time the loop goes through an iteration, the string gets rewritten with the new iteration. Is there any way to prevent this?

```
for i in range(0,len(string1)):
    newString = string1[i] + string2[i]
return newString
```

newString only comes out as the last iteration when I need to newString to be the first iteration to the last.

Comment: What are you trying to do to it each iteration? Append `string1[i] + string2[i]` to the end? Please be more clear.

Comment: How about `''.join([char for t in zip(string1, string2) for char in t])`

Comment: you are setting the value every single iteration. what do you want to do? to append them to a big list? if so you need to use += operator. if you will add expected input and output it will be more clear what you are trying to achive

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accumulate all of per-iteration values, try using the aggregate assignment operator `+=`. The following code will return one very long string, which is the concatenation of all of the intermediate strings.

```
newString = ''
for i in range(0,len(string1)):
    newString += string1[i] + string2[i]
return newString
```

Alternatively, you might want to return a list of the intermediate values, like so:

```
newList = []
for i in range(0,len(string1)):
    newList += [string1[i] + string2[i]]
return newList
```

Note, however, that it is often a bad idea to append strings in a loop. It causes a lot of memory reallocation. The typical Pythonic form is to collect the intermediate values into a list and `''.join()` them together, like so:

```
newList = []
for i in range(0,len(string1)):
    newList += [string1[i] + string2[i]]
newString = ''.join(newList)
return newString
```

Equivalently, and more compactly,

```
return ''.join(''.join(chars) for chars in zip(string1, string2))
```

Comment: Oh same as doing numbers, I feel dumb. Thanks for the help!